# Error from AddConditionalFormatRule

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I am trying to apply a conditional format to a spreadsheet that I am creating using the Sheets API. However, there is one section of my code which always causes an exception.

Specifically, the exception message is:

```
Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The service is currently unavailable. [503]
Errors [
        Message[The service is currently unavailable.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]
```

This is the section of code that is related to the exception:

```
Request request4 = new Request();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule = new AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule = new ConditionalFormatRule();
GridRange range1 = new GridRange();
range1.SheetId = 0;
range1.StartColumnIndex = 8;
range1.EndColumnIndex = 9;
range1.StartRowIndex = 1;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.Ranges = new List<GridRange>();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.Ranges.Add(range1);
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule = new GradientRule();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint = new InterpolationPoint();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Type = "MIN";
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Color = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Color();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Color.Red = 1;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Color.Green = (float)0.48;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Color.Blue = (float)0.48;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint = new InterpolationPoint();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Type = "NUMBER";
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Value = "0.5";
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Color = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Color();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Color.Red = 1;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Color.Green = 1;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Midpoint.Color.Blue = 0;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint = new InterpolationPoint();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint.Type = "MAX";
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint.Color = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Color();
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint.Color.Red = (float)0.82;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint.Color.Green = 1;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Maxpoint.Color.Blue = (float)0.87;
request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Index = 0;
requests.Add(request4);
```

As you can probably assume, this is part of a number of Request objects that I am sending together as a `BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest`. If I comment out this section of problematic code, then everything else works perfectly.

The spreadsheet data is generated dynamically, but always contains 14 columns and between 4000 and 5000 rows.

Does anyone know what is causing this exception, and perhaps can share some advice on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with using InterpolationPointType's MIN & MAX.  The documentation says that no "value" is required (and indeed the value shouldn't be required), but the server has a bug right now where it requires it.  I've identified the problem and will post here when the fix is rolled out.  As a workaround for now, use a dummy value, e.g, 
 `request4.AddConditionalFormatRule.Rule.GradientRule.Minpoint.Value = "1"`, and same for the maxpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes that solution has worked.

Comment: I wonder if you happen to know how to solve this enum problem in a Google Sheets Apps Script https://stackoverflow.com/q/48655476/470749 Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to post the update here -- we fixed this on the server side in June 2016, so you shouldn't need to do the workaround anymore.