# How to write the MIN, MID, MAX enums in Google Sheets when trying to create gradient conditional formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

**How can I use an [InterpolationPointType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#InterpolationPointType) enum in the following script?**

See the commented lines with the hand pointers to see where I'm hitting an error: `Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_conditional_format_rule.rule.gradient_rule.midpoint.type' (TYPE_ENUM)`

I'm excited about what I'm designing here and think I'm close to achieving a script that can dynamically add color gradient conditional formatting to a Google Sheet.

But I haven't found a way around this enum problem even when looking at docs for [ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#conditionalformatrule), [Gradient rules](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format#gradient_rules), and [Add a conditional color gradient across a row](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting#add_a_conditional_color_gradient_across_a_row).

```
function addGradients(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("temp");
  var requests = [];

  //Do this for as many ranges as needed:
  var myRange = Sheets.newGridRange();
  myRange.sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  myRange.startRowIndex = 12;
  myRange.endRowIndex = 24;
  myRange.startColumnIndex = 4;
  myRange.endColumnIndex = 4;  
  var request1 = addGradientToRange(myRange);
  requests.push(request1);

  // Batch send the requests  
  var batchUpdate = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchUpdate.requests = requests;
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdate, ss.getId());
}

function addGradientToRange(myRange){
  var rule1GradientRule = Sheets.newGradientRule();
  var ptMax = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();
  var ptMid = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();
  var ptMin = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();  
  var colorGreen = Sheets.newColor();
  colorGreen.green = 1;
  var colorRed = Sheets.newColor();
  colorRed.red = 1;
  var colorWhite = Sheets.newColor();  

  ptMax.color = colorGreen;  
  ptMid.color = colorWhite;
  ptMin.color = colorRed;
  ptMax.type = "MAX";// What can I type here to set it to this enum?
  ptMid.type = "MID";// What can I type here to set it to this enum?
  ptMin.type = "MIN";// What can I type here to set it to this enum?
  rule1GradientRule.maxpoint = ptMax;
  rule1GradientRule.midpoint = ptMid;
  rule1GradientRule.minpoint = ptMin;

  var rule1 = Sheets.newConditionalFormatRule();
  rule1.ranges = [myRange];
  rule1.gradientRule = rule1GradientRule;

  var request1 = Sheets.newRequest();
  var addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1 = Sheets.newAddConditionalFormatRuleRequest();
  addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1.rule = rule1;
  addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1.index = 0;
  request1.addConditionalFormatRule = addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1;
  return request1;
}
```

And if I don't specify the `.type` for each InterpolationPoint, I get this error: `Invalid requests[0].addConditionalFormatRule: No interpolationPointType specified.`

I've also tried `ptMax.type = InterpolationPointType.Max;`, but then I get error: `ReferenceError: "InterpolationPointType" is not defined.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

- There is no `"MID"` in the [InterpolationPointType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#InterpolationPointType). If you want to give a middle value, you can use `"PERCENT"` for type and `"50"` for value.
- If you want to give "white" to the middle, please use 1, 1 and 1 for red, green and blue, respectively. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Color)

The modified script is as follows. I modified `addGradientToRange()`.

### Modified script :

```
function addGradientToRange(myRange){
  var rule1GradientRule = Sheets.newGradientRule();
  var ptMax = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();
  var ptMid = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();
  var ptMin = Sheets.newInterpolationPoint();  
  var colorGreen = Sheets.newColor();
  colorGreen.green = 1;
  var colorRed = Sheets.newColor();
  colorRed.red = 1;
  var colorWhite = Sheets.newColor();
  colorWhite.red = 1; // Added
  colorWhite.green = 1; // Added
  colorWhite.blue = 1; // Added

  ptMax.color = colorGreen;  
  ptMid.color = colorWhite;
  ptMin.color = colorRed;
  ptMax.type = "MAX";
  ptMid.type = "PERCENT"; // Modified
  ptMid.value = "50"; // Added
  ptMin.type = "MIN";
  rule1GradientRule.maxpoint = ptMax;
  rule1GradientRule.midpoint = ptMid;
  rule1GradientRule.minpoint = ptMin;

  var rule1 = Sheets.newConditionalFormatRule();
  rule1.ranges = [myRange];
  rule1.gradientRule = rule1GradientRule;

  var request1 = Sheets.newRequest();
  var addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1 = Sheets.newAddConditionalFormatRuleRequest();
  addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1.rule = rule1;
  addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1.index = 0;
  request1.addConditionalFormatRule = addConditionalFormatRuleRequest1;
  return request1;
}
```

### Sample result :

This sample was applied to the range of "A1:E20".

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: You are so awesome. Thank you so much. I'd forgotten about MID needing to be PERCENT.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a more modern method doing that (gradient conditional formatting), by using the ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder Class.
(See [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)) 
this is a general function that gets a sheet name and a range, and sets a new rule with 0 as mid point, green as max and red as min:

```js
//add a general gradiant conditional formatting with max=green, mid=white, min=red background
function addGradientToRange(theSheet, myRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(theSheet);
  var range = sheet.getRange(myRange);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setGradientMaxpoint("#00FF00")
    .setGradientMidpointWithValue("#FFFFFF", SpreadsheetApp.InterpolationType.NUMBER, "0")
    .setGradientMinpoint("#FF0000")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Hope that helps....